# Torsion groups for commutative rings - row reduction?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, k-theory

Let $A$ be a ring.  Then we have the group 
$$
GL(A) = \bigcup_{i =1}^\infty GL_n(A)
$$ 
which we can abelianize to form the torsion group $K(A)$.  In the case where $A$ is commutative, we have a homorphism to the group of units
$$
\text{det} : K(A) \to A^\times
$$
which has kernel $SK(A)$.  I was learning about this stuff by looking at Milnor's article on Whitehead torsion and he makes the remark that $SK(A) = 1$ if and only if every determinant one matrix in $GL(A)$ is equivalent to the identity matrix via some number of elementary row operations.

I do not understand either direction of this equivalence - I guess I am missing some linear algebra observations.  Could someone elaborate on this equivalence?

Comment: This is a long story and I think you should read a book on $K$-theory. One of the important facts used is that $[SL(A),SL((A)]$, the commutator subgroup of $SL(A)$ is $E(A)$, the group generated by elementary matrices (aka row and column operations). There are no one line proof for this fact.